# How should proper nouns using stylized case (e.g.: ownCloud) be treated in formal writing?

Tags: writing-style, capitalization

Many companies are now using stylized case for their names. When writing formal documents, how should these names be written? Assuming that the case they've chosen should be honored, how should they be treated at the beginning of a sentence?

Answer (score -1):

I think we just have to accept it.

Example

> iPad Air is just 7.5 millimetres thin and weighs less than half a kilo. 
>   [apple.com](http://www.apple.com/uk/shop/buy-ipad/ipad-air)

The problem would come if the name was all in lower case. Perhaps italics would be necessary.